# Trying to understand changing UI in React with Conditionals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I’ve been learning react off and on for the last six months. I understand how it works, how to make components and all the core fundamentals of the library.

However one thing has me tripped up.
I have only made smaller applications so far, as I haven’t learnt enough to go take on bigger projects (not corporate size but something like a SPA).

My question is this: When changing UI with State you use a lot of conditional blocks to change what’s being rendered. How does this look on a big scale? Let’s say I want to show 6 different views each with many different components, isn’t that going to be conditional after conditional? Isn’t that hard to manage with all the conditionals in the return/render?
Am I missing something (I almost certainly am) or is this how react is? I can’t find any resources explaining how you would go about structuring these views in react and I don’t want to hack together something doing it my way if it’s not the best practice or going to cause issues later.
I have heard of React-Router and that makes sense that it could help for this scenario, but I still would like to know if I’m thinking of react wrong here or missing a core concept..

If someone could break this down for me I’d be so appreciative

Comment: "Let’s say I want to show 6 different views each with many different components", You would do this using a router, as each view is considered a "page" of the app. You can use something like `react-router` for that. As for the different components in each view, the conditionals wouldn't all be in the same file as the conditions would likely be spread throughout the app, and therefore throughout the component tree. If you find yourself using `if... else... if... else... if...else...` in a single render function, then break that component up into smaller components to separate the logic.

Comment: A good rule to go by is that if you can move state further down the tree (into child components) then do it. A parent component doesn't need to handle the logic of its children if the children can do that for themselves. For situations where you need to share state across many disconnected parts of the app (for example, user state such as name, email, and isAuthenticated) you can use React's context API.

Comment: Both these answers are very helpful! I think coming from a more traditional front-end and not using conditionals to render UI, I thought I was doing something wrong.
Now I understand it is how complex UI is rendered in React and it is more about the management of the logic/conditionals rather than trying to use them less!